# Find the number of nearest neighbour cluster

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor

I clustered my data set using fuzzy c-means. Now whenever a new data set comes in picture, I want to know the number of nearest neighbourhood from each cluster to the coming point. Please provide me the Matlab codes.

Comment: Where iz the codez! Gimme the codez! -1

Comment: Anony m also asking for the codes...if u have any such code please provide it to me

Comment: We wants the codez, we needs the codez. Must have the precious codezz. They stole it from us. Sneaky little hobbitses. Wicked, tricksy, false!

Comment: hobbitses are the real hero.....neither wicked,tricksy nor false...

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzy c-means clustering can done with [fcm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fcm.html) provided with the [Fuzzy Logic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/fuzzy-logic/). To view the code, enter:

```
edit fcm
```

Comment: Sir very thankful to you for replying me but i want to incorporate the spatial characteristics in the fuzzy c means. cn u provide the elaborated matlab codes for fuzzy c means so that i can modify the objective  function

Comment: `edit fcm` should provide the elaborated matlab codes for fuzzy c means.

Comment: Than You Sir....sir i have one more query.....how to reduce the computational time of fuzzy c means

Comment: No idea. Probably worth another question :)

Comment: sir i did it...thanx for valuable support